# Is there a jQuery equivalent to prototype Element.request()

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, prototypejs

With Prototype, I used to type:

```
$("my_form").request();
```

This is supposed to perform an AJAX request of form#my_form. I Googled a bit but all I found is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, which doesn't really suits my need since I have to specify URL, data's, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) allows you to perform AJAX requests from web forms:

```
$("#my_form").ajaxForm(function() {
    window.alert("Form submitted.");
});
```